# Exponential function of a complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For real $z$, It is true that $f(z) = \exp(z) > 0$. However, if $z$ is now complex, is this statement still true?

Thanks.

Comment: The field of complex numbers is not an ordered field.

Comment: For most complex $z$, you will find $\exp(z)$ is a complex number so not comparable to $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{\pi i}  =-1, \text{ so no, not positive } \forall z.$$

Actually, $f(z)=\exp(z)$ is not real for many $z$.

Comment: Indeed, exp is an analytic function. And the only way for an analytic function $f$ defined on an open subset of $\Bbb C$ to take only real values is for $f$ to be constant.

Comment: @Lubin,  That's rather deep! Why is that?

Comment: It is deepish. A non constant analytic function is an open mapping, i.e. it sends opens to opens.

Comment: Do you have a reference or two to recommend to read up on this?

Comment: Oh, everything I know I got from Ahlfors. I’ve forgotten the details, but I think the openness of the associated mapping should drop right out of the Cauchy-Riemann equations. You’d have to check that.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll take a look ...